# Ruby on Rails integrable CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I need to integrate a blog in my web app, but it would be pretty cool if I could use an existing CMS.

It doesn't have to be a CMS developed in RoR. Actually, if you know about a CMS with an good API it would be just great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mephisto is pretty good. It's in Rails, and has a bunch of neat drop-in functions. You can migrate your data over with a simple yaml export/import or something.

http://swik.net/mephisto